# .Net Library to read NXP I-Code SLIX Tag?

Tags: library, software-development, .net

We would like to read NDEF records as well as Tag ID from our tags coming from production using any suitable .Net library.

Currently these data are read using Android NFC lib but using NFC reader from android device like mobile phone are not really an industrial way of processing hundred of tags.

As we also have .Net skills in our team we look if we could leverage this tag scanning operation in our logistic process using any dedicated reader. But as far as I saw this kind of NXP ICode SLIX tag are poorly supported in the .Net community.

I add a couple of sample data screenshot from one of our tag, the first one helps to identify which kind of tag it is, the second one shows data we want to read underlined in red:

[image]

[image: Data]

So if you had any good experience in doing so, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

To get things done I asked directly to NXP Support. So they advise me to choose from their known RFID hardware partner. HID and FEIG.

**HID Ominkey with pcsc-sharp**

First I successfully achieved reading memory using an HID Omnikey 5022 reader and this [PC/SC .Net Lib from Github](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) which is meanly a wrapper on winscard.dll. This combination is working great as there is a built-in support of event like card detection. The only inconvenient is it only supports read single block (4 bytes) so I had to code a kind memory parser like following :

```
    private const Byte RADIOID_BLOCK_START = 0x03;
    private const Byte RADIOID_BLOCK_START_OFFSET = 0x01;
    private const Byte RADIOID_LENGHT = 0x08;

    private const Byte MACADDRESS_BLOCK_START = 0x07;
    private const Byte MACADDRESS_BLOCK_START_OFFSET = 0x00;
    private const Byte MACADDRESS_LENGHT = 0x11;
    private const String MACADDRESS_EMPTYVALUE = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";


    private String GetRadioId(IIsoReader isoReader)
    {
        Byte[] radioId = ReadMultipleBlock(isoReader, RADIOID_BLOCK_START, RADIOID_BLOCK_START_OFFSET,RADIOID_LENGHT);
        String strData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(radioId, 0, radioId.Length);

        Debug.WriteLine($"RadioId Data :{strData}");

        return strData;
    }


    private String GetMacAdress(IIsoReader isoReader)
    {
        Byte[] data = ReadMultipleBlock(isoReader,MACADDRESS_BLOCK_START, MACADDRESS_BLOCK_START_OFFSET, MACADDRESS_LENGHT);
        String strData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
        Debug.WriteLine($"MAC Data :{strData}");
        return strData;
    }


    private Byte[] ReadMultipleBlock(IIsoReader isoReader, Byte blockStart, Byte offset, Byte dataLength)
    {
        Byte[] dataRead = new Byte[dataLength];
        Byte currentBlock = blockStart;
        Byte index = 0;

        while (index < dataLength)
        {
            // Build a READ Single Binary Block command 
            CommandApdu cmdApdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case2Short, SCardProtocol.Any)
            {
                CLA = 0xFF,
                INS = 0xB0,
                P1 = 0x00,
                P2 = currentBlock,
                Le = 0x04
            };

            Debug.WriteLine($"<-- { BitConverter.ToString(cmdApdu.ToArray())}");
            Response response = isoReader.Transmit(cmdApdu);

            if (!response.HasData)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("No data. (Card does not understand \"ReadBinary\")"));
                return dataRead;
            }
            else
            {
                Byte[] data = response.GetData();
                Debug.WriteLine($"--> {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length)}");
                Byte responseIndex = 0;

                if (currentBlock == blockStart)
                {
                    responseIndex = offset;
                }

                while (responseIndex <= 0x03 && index < dataLength)
                {
                    dataRead[index++] = data[responseIndex++];
                }
                currentBlock++;
            }
        }

        return dataRead;
    }
```

**ISO 15693 using FEIG Reader API**

We tested with success a [Feig RFID reader](https://www.feig.de/en/products/identification/product/id-iscspad102/) which comes with a .Net API. Even if the documentation is still in "preliminary" stage it is working fine. It allows Read Multiple Block Command but does not come with event like card detection buit-in. So for the moment we loop infinitely over inventory to produce a kind of "Tag Inserted event" using their so called "Host Mode". There is a "Scan Mode" which might act as an event producer but didn't had time yet to dig deeper with it. So I read several memory blocks in a single call and then parsed them by code. I do not show you the code as I'm not sure I am allowed to put sample code of this copyrighted API but it is very similar to the previous above except of course I didn't loop to get several block of data.

I wish there will come a native NDEF message in some API one day to avoid parsing code ...